# Selection Sort Implementation with C++ incorrect

Tags: c++, algorithm

really new to C++, trying to instantiate some basic algorithms with it. Having trouble returning the correct result for selection sort. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Selection Sort :

int findMin(vector<int> &arr, int a)
{
    int m = a;
    for (int i = a + 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[m])
        {
            m = i;
        }
        return m;
    }
}

void swap(int &a, int &b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void selectionSort(vector<int> &arr)
{
    if (!arr.empty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
        {
            int min = findMin(arr, i);
            swap(arr[i], arr[min]); // Assume a correct swap function
        }
    }
}

void print(vector<int> &arr)
{
    if (!arr.empty())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << arr[i] << "";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> sort;
    sort.push_back(2);
    sort.push_back(1);
    sort.push_back(7);
    sort.push_back(4);
    sort.push_back(5);
    sort.push_back(3);
    print(sort);
    cout << "this was unsorted array";
    cout << endl;
    cout << findMin(sort, 0);
    cout << "this was minimum";
    cout << endl;

    selectionSort(sort);
    print(sort);
}
```

I am getting the following results:

```
comparison_sort.cpp:20:1: warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
1 warning generated.
2
1
7
4
5
3
this was unsorted array
1
this was minimum
1
2
4
5
3
0
```

My question is: What is causing this control path error? Why is the "7" here being replaced with a "0"?

Thanks in advance! Sorry for the noob question.

I have reviewed all my current functions and nothing seems to explain why the 7 is replaced with a 0. I have tried multiple integers and it looks like the maximum number is always replaced.

Comment: The warning is saying your function does not return a value if the loop body never executes.

Comment: Side-note: there's no need to define your own `swap` function.  Use `std::swap`.

Comment: Hi Paddy, thanks for your quick response. It seems the error refers to my findMin function. However adding a if (!arr.empty()) guard doesn't seem to fix this issue.

Also, any ideas why the 7 here is replaced with a 0?

Comment: Of course that doesn't fix the warning.  The compiler doesn't know what `arr.empty()` has any relationship to `arr.size()`, and it has no idea what value of `a` might be passed into the function. Why don't you have it return a value after the loop?  Your function should always return a value.  From all control paths.  Fixing this issue is likely to answer your question about why the 7 is replaced with a 0.

Comment: To emphasize what paddy already said: If the condition in `if (arr[i] < arr[m])` is not `true` at any time in the loop, what will the function return? Nothing.

Comment: Thanks guys, recognize the issue now. :)

Comment: You have two strong hints: one is the compiler warning, it contains the answer. The other is a value strangely modified, indicating an Undefined Behavior; these are quite often caused by out-of-array-bounds accesses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is very real, and it alludes to the problem that's breaking your sort as well.

You are currently returning `m` inside your loop body.  What that means is that if the loop is entered, then the function will return `m` on the very first time around the loop.  It only has a chance to check the first element.

And of course, if `a` is the last index of the array, then the loop will never execute, and you will never explicitly return a value.  This is the "control path" which does not return a value.

It's quite clear that you've accidentally put `return m;` in the wrong place, and even though you have good code indentation, some inexplicable force is preventing you from seeing this.  To fix both the warning and the sorting issue, move `return m;` outside the loop:

```
int findMin(vector<int> &arr, int a)
{
    int m = a;
    for (int i = a + 1; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] < arr[m])
        {
            m = i;
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```